# change width of containers based on number hidden - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having a problem with changing the width of the containers based on what is hidden and shown.

I have 5 containers nested inside of a main container. Each nested container consumes roughly `20%` of the width in the main container. I need to be able to collapse two of the containers while still consuming 100% width of the main container.

Basically if the user clicks collapsible container number one the clicked container width shrinks to `5%` and all of the other containers (4) grow to roughly `23%` to fill in the space.

Now if the user clicks the second collapsible container while the other one is still collapsed, the clicked container should also shrink to `5%` and the other containers (3) should grow to roughly `30%` to consume the remaining space.

So in the above scenario with both collapsible containers clicked there should be two `5%` wide containers and three `30%` wide containers.

Now if both containers are collapsed and the user clicks one of the collapsed containers, the clicked container should grow leaving the other collapsed container at `5%` while all the other containers change size to roughly `23%`. If the remaining collapsed container is clicked, the clicked container, along with all of the other containers should change size to `20%` so that they all fill the main containers width.

I kind of have it working. You can see that when you click `Four` and then `Five` that the containers shrink and the others grow. But when you click them again to make them grow, the other containers do not change size.

I have played with this for quite a while now to make it work and it should be very simple but for some reason it is giving me fits.

Hopefully this makes sense. I have included some code below along with a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKorKY).

```
$('#collapse1 .header, #collapse2 .header').on('click', function() {
  clicked = $(this).parent();
  $(clicked).toggleClass('collapsed-column');

  var num = $('.collapsed-column').length;

  if (num == 1) {
    $('.col-5ths').not(clicked).toggleClass('collapsed-1');
    $('.col-5ths').removeClass('collapsed-2')
    if ($(clicked).hasClass('.collapsed-2')) {
      $(clicked).addClass('.collapsed-1');
    }
  } else if (num == 2) {
    $('.col-5ths').not(clicked).toggleClass('collapsed-2');

  } else {
    $('.col-5ths').removeClass('collapsed-2 collapsed-1 collapsed-column')
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-5ths">
    <div class="header">
      one
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5ths">
    <div class="header">
      two
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5ths"><div class="header">
      three
    </div></div>
  <div class="col-5ths collapsible" id="collapse1">
    <div class="header">
      four
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5ths collapsible" id="collapse2">
    <div class="header">
      five
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I’d rather solve this by toggling classes on the parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a working example based on what I understood from your question in [HERE](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/vLZeZo). In this example, you click on the first `div` and its width changes to 5% while others' width increases to almost 23.75%. In this condition, when you click on the second `div`, it will do the 5% for it and the rest (except first div) goes to almost 30%.

if you need any other functionality, you can simply added to the JS logic in the example.

Comment: You are kind of close. Look at my updated question and codepen I added. I got it close to what I need but there is still a bug in the code.

Comment: @Yamaha32088: I got your question now and I fixed the example accordingly. You can check it now  http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/vLZeZo